# How can I use errors.Is on an error created by errors.Wrap?

Tags: go, error-handling

I like to do this:

```
var ErrMyCustomError = errors.New("something went wrong")

func doAThing(input string) error {
    if input == "bad input" {
        return ErrMyCustomError
    }
    return nil
}
```

And then in my tests:

```
func TestFailCase() {
    err := doAThing("bad input")
    require.True(errors.Is(err, ErrMyCustomError)
}
```

My question is how do I do all that but have `return ErrMyCustomError` instead wrap an error I got from somewhere else in an `ErrMyCustomError` (so that the `errors.Is` still works).

```
func doAThing(input string) error {
    err := doSomething(input)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "some context message") // <-- this line here needs to return an ErrMyCustomError somehow but also wrap err
    }
}

// Imagine this is in some third party lib and I can't alter it.
func doSomething(input string) error {
    if input == "bad input" {
        return errors.New("some error I will later wrap")
    }
    return nil
}

func TestFailCase() {
    err := doAThing("bad input")
    require.True(errors.Is(err, ErrMyCustomError) // <-- this is no longer true but I want it to be
}
```

Comment: In the second example, nothing in the error chain is an `ErrMyCustomError`. You're not wrapping a `ErrMyCustomError`, you're wrapping `errors.New("some error I will later wrap")`. If you change `doSomething` to `return ErrMyCustomError` it should work as expected.

Comment: `doSomething` here is a placeholder for something like a third-party lib or some part of my code that doesn't know about `ErrMyCustomError`. So I want to do the wrapping in `doAThing` specifically. (Updated the question to make this a bit clearer.)

Comment: You can't wrap another error in an error *value*, because then it would be a different value. To get the functionality you're describing, you want an error *type*, and to use `errors.As` instead of `errors.Is`.

Comment: Conceptually I just want an error chain that looks like: 

`{error-i-got-from-doSomething, ErrMyCustomError, "my additional context"}`

so that I can ask `errors.Is(err, ErrMyCustomError)` and get `true` but also be able to add my additional context. I will look into `errors.As`

Comment: I took a look at `errors.As` and although it's real close to what I want it's a func for operating on a chain of errors. What I'm looking for is a way to create that chain in the first place. As @Adrian says it's probable that I need a type to do that, not simply a value. That feels a lot clunkier to me than just being able to say `err2 := errors.MyWrapFunc(ErrMyCustomErr, err)` so that I can say `errors.Is(err2, ErrMyCustomErr)` later and get `true`.

Comment: You absolutely need a type. An error value is meant to be static and global; to wrap another error in that error, you'd have to change its value, which would change it globally. In order to have error A wrap anything, A *must* be a type, not a value.

Comment: I wonder if that means the pattern of even having `var ErrMyCustomError = errors.New("blah")` anywhere in code is wrong. There isn't one instance of this happening ever, it's a type of error, so that would make sense. However I see that pattern being used in the Go 1.13 error handling post and in ErrConnDone, ErrNoRows, ErrTxDone in https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/ (for example) which makes me feel like it's an expected style. Probably that dates from before `errors.Is` existed so this problem didn't exist then to suggest a different approach.

Comment: Indeed, most of the stdlib error values predate error wrapping support. I wouldn't say that all use of error values is "wrong" though - some errors just are what they are, like `io.EOF`. You'd never wrap another error in `io.EOF`, and you'd never need specific context for that error either. An error value is appropriate for that case. An error type would also work, but an error value isn't really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I have been able to come up with. I'd prefer to just `var MyCustomErr = errors.New("something went wrong")` but then I have no way to get it into the error chain. I'd prefer to `errors.Is` rather than having to declare a receiver pointer to check `errors.As` but so far I haven't found a way to do that either.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type MyCustomError struct {
    Err   error
}

func (e MyCustomError) Error() string {
    return "something went wrong: " + e.Err.Error()
}

func main() {
    err := myWrapper()
    ptr := &MyCustomError{}
    print(errors.As(err, ptr)) // prints "true"
}

func myWrapper() error {
    err := thirdPartyFunc()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("some additional context: %w", MyCustomError{Err: err})
    }
    return nil
}

func thirdPartyFunc() error {
    return errors.New("this is the error I want to wrap")
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared a pointer receiver anywhere in this code, but if you're referring to the use of a pointer value in calling `errors.As`, you could instead say `var myErr MyCustomError; print(errors.As(err, &myError))` if you don't want to declare the variable as a pointer type.